# How can I write a macro that creates a text file when a table has been changed?

Tags: ms-access, vba, text-files

I am trying to create a macro that when a table is changed it will create a simple text file to a chosen path. I have been programming in VB.NET but access is in vba, I have been doing some research and think I can do it. However access macro writer confuses me if the boxes you insert your code in to. Is there a way to make one in VB.NET or use Visual Studio that access would be able to use?

Comment: Why are you using a macro? Are you using Access 2010 and [data macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807.aspx)? If not, why not straight VBA rather than macros?

Comment: Im using 2010 but not data macros, how to I code straight in VBA is there a tool within access to allow this, or should I do it straight in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can select from the menu, press alt+F11, or choose an event from a property sheet and select code from the option. Adding code to events is a major strength of MS Access from and reports.

Comment: I'm having a look at the data macros and using code behind to add my functionality. But the buttons seem to be disabled and I can't work out how to enable them

Comment: Can you edit tables? Can you add forms? Can you change tables in design view? There are a few reasons why you may not be able to use the buttons, so a few notes on what you can do may help. It is always a good idea to try opening the file while holding the shift-key down, to bypass start-up code.

Comment: I can do all the above but the disabled buttons are the same. I think that your code will work, if only I could get the data macros to work. Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16483/discussion-between-remou-and-teamgb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think you should take advantage of data macros. These will run even if the table is used outside of MS Access. For example:

[image]

Alternatively

```
Sub LogThis(strText)
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim sPath As String
Dim fs As Object
Dim ts As Object

    sPath = CurrentProject.Path

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fs.FileExists(sPath & "\Log.txt") = True Then
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(sPath & "\Log.txt", ForAppending)
    Else
        Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(sPath & "\Log.txt")
    End If
    ts.WriteLine Now & " " & strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
```